# urge + subject + verb structure?

Tags: sentence-construction

You usually use ***urge that clause***, but do you sometimes omit ***that*** in that structure? I looked up several dictionaries, but I couldn't find the example sentences without ***that***.

- The charity urged the government to reconsider its decision.  ( ○ )
- The charity urged that the government reconsider its decision.  ( ○ )
- The charity urged the government reconsider its decision. ( ? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence is the most natural. The second is passable, but is rather more formal.

The third sentence is pretty borderline. The problem is it's something of a "garden path sentence", in that the reader/listener is expecting the word "to", which never comes.

So, I would say, it's probably technically grammatically correct, but a confusing choice in practice.